# Does an authenticated REST request ALWAYS implies a database request?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, basic-authentication, objectify

I'm using RESTeasy framework to develop my web service. I've managed to set up BASIC authentication, and it is working properly now. Of course, I do plan to use SSL on top of this.

The process is simple (and please [read something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) about HTTP basic Auth if you don't know what this is about):

1. Every request is intercepted by a method which analyzes the request header.
2. This header is decoded and the username and password are extracted.
3. The method then **queries the database** to check if the username and password match.
4. If they match the request proceeds, if they don't, a 401 code is returned.

With this approach, every request implies a request to the database, due to the stateless nature of REST (and HTTP itself).

My question is: Is it possible to don't query the database on every authenticated request?

Possible hints: Some mechanism using cookies?

This question is technologically agnostic.

---

Just as a side note:

I really feel that there is very little information on this REST authentication matter. It's just OAuth, OAuth, OAuth... If we don't want to authenticate 3rd party applications, information is scattered everywhere and there aren't any concrete examples, like there are using OAuth.
If you have any good advises regarding Authentication in REST WebServices, I would love to hear them.

Thank you.

Comment: there is this new thing called caching you might want to research up on it!

Comment: It doesn't imply a database request if your credentials are stored in a file :-)

Comment: @cbuckley A file request is potentially slower than a database request, so I think it really isn't an option.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm using Google App Engine. I'll look in its documentation.

Comment: @miguelcobain I was just being pedantic :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It seems that GAE has support to [memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html). I think that's good news, right? :)

Comment: I am confused. Why would you think that HTTP/REST statelessness implies that the implementation of the service is also stateless?

Comment: @DonalFellows You are right. Perhaps I was too focused on some principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up to be **cache**.

In my particular case I was using RESTeasy as a REST framework and Google App Engine as the Application Server. It wasn't hard to find out that GAE has support to [memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html).

If you're using [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) (you really should; it's awesome), it's even easier. Just annotate your entity classes with *@Cached*. This procedure is illustrated [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Caching).

Objectify supports another kind of cache in a session Object. In other words, as long your Objectify object is instantiated, it can provide your objects even without using memcache (This is good because in GAE there quotas for using memcache, although they are cheaper than the datastore ones). I strongly advise you to read Objectify's good practices in their wiki.

As a final note, I'll consider using *Digest authentication* instead of *Basic*. It seems much more secure. The fact that the password never travels through the network really reliefs me.

I hope that this SO question was useful to someone and for those who helped me: thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to implement an "Auth Ticket" (google that and you'll probably find some non-OAuth references) with cookies so that not every request requires a database query. However, these usually involve a crypto key.

I'm not convinced that best practices should be to store the crypto key in the source files (but this is how tutorials usually implement it), so you might involve some sort of disk access (via properties file, keystore, etc) even if you don't query a database.

As Perception states, adding cookies (state) to a stateless system design is sort of cheating.

Comment: Thank you for your "Auth Ticket" insight. I'll look further into that.

Comment: @miguelcobain: I just implemented one for a client last night (I just used pyramid's built in stuff with py-bcrypt for the actual random-salt-hashed pw). In other words: I cheated.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) as an intermediate to your database. Check if credentials are cached, if they are continue with the request, if they are not cached, pull them from the database and verify the credentials. If the credentials match cache them for future requests and continue with the current one.

Keep in mind that access to memchaced must be as secure as access to your database since it hass passwords stored in it. This is one of the reasons So many sites are using OAuth, especially OAuth 2 where you hand out a short lived access token and a long lived refresh token that will get a new access token when needed.

Comment: It seems that GAE has support to [memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html). I think that's good news, right? :)

Comment: Yep. It should be pretty easy to implement then.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Representational State Tranfer Security! You know, I sent a message to Roy Fielding asking how you could create a truly RESTful service that was also secure. He hasn't gotten back to me yet.

Your two options really are Basic Auth (hopefully using SSL, or what's the point), or OAuth. For all the solutions I am currently involved with we are using OAuth. While it complicates testing it is very secure and allows us to create externalizable API's out of our services.

I advice against using cookies to store session information. Not only does this violate the spirit of REST, but it also opens up your application to session hijacking. One thing that you can do to speed things up is maintain a good second level cache with user information, so that your queries don't actually hit the DB for every incoming requests. This can give a ***significant*** speed boost. This tactic works equally well for both basic auth and Oauth.

Comment: I've updated the question to mention that I will use SSL, of course.
I'm using Google App Engine and its datastore. I'll investigate what kind of caching this infrastructure supports. I would benefit a lot from reducing the datastore requests because in GAE we pay from a certain number of requests. :) Thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: It seems that GAE has support to [memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html). I think that's good news, right? :) Unfortunately there are also quotas for using this service.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the ORM tools available in GAE, but memcached is reliable and fast, so that *is* good news.

Comment: There is Objectify that provides an abstraction to the datastore. It supports caching using memcache and using a local HashMap. Everything transparent. Also, the memcache quotas are much higher than the datastore ones, so it makes sense to use memcache whenever possible. Thank you! :)

Comment: There are other practical auth schemes for REST services too. HTTP Digest Auth works well, and SSL with client certificates is very strong (if a total deployment PITA with sites for the general public). Arguably OAuth is the most problematic as it can involve lots of third party futzing around…

Comment: Yes, I've considered HTTP Digest Auth as well. HTTP Basic seems to have an advantage: with just one request the user can be Authenticated. HTTP Digest requires one extra round trip time to obtain the nounce, if I correctly remember. However, HTTP Digest never sends the password through the network. I need to weight very well these to. Which one would you advise: Basic or Digest? I suppose there is plenty of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate with the UserService of AppEninge (and as such with Google accounts), then you can prevent any queries. RESTlet has a super elegant authenticator that comes with the framework :

```
public class GaeAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    /**
     * The GAE UserService that provides facilities to check whether a user has
     * authenticated using their Google Account
     */
    private UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    /**
     * Constructor setting the mode to "required".
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @see #Authenticator(Context)
     */
    public GaeAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor using the context's default enroler.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @param optional
     *            The authentication mode.
     * @see #Authenticator(Context, boolean, Enroler)
     */
    public GaeAuthenticator(Context context, boolean optional) {
        super(context, optional);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @param optional
     *            The authentication mode.
     * @param enroler
     *            The enroler to invoke upon successful authentication.
     */
    public GaeAuthenticator(Context context, boolean optional, Enroler enroler) {
        super(context, optional, enroler);
    }

    /**
     * Integrates with Google App Engine UserService to redirect
     * non-authenticated users to the GAE login URL. Upon successful login,
     * creates a Restlet User object based values in GAE user object. The GAE
     * "nickname" property gets mapped to the Restlet "firstName" property.
     * 
     * @param request
     *            The request sent.
     * @param response
     *            The response to update.
     * @return True if the authentication succeeded.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
        ClientInfo info = request.getClientInfo();
        if (info.isAuthenticated()) {
            // The request is already authenticated.
            return true;
        } else if (userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            // The user is logged in, create restlet user.
            com.google.appengine.api.users.User gaeUser = userService
                    .getCurrentUser();
            User restletUser = new User(gaeUser.getUserId());
            restletUser.setEmail(gaeUser.getEmail());
            restletUser.setFirstName(gaeUser.getNickname());
            info.setUser(restletUser);
            info.setAuthenticated(true);
            return true;
        } else {
            // The GAE user service says user not logged in, let's redirect him
            // to the login page.
            String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(request
                    .getOriginalRef().toString());
            response.redirectTemporary(loginUrl);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be a good solution, but need to authenticate my own users, not Google's. Also, I'm using RESTeasy.
But thank you for letting me know of this feature. :)